# Open Xml PowerTools throwing error Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'attribute')

Tags: openxml, openxml-powertools

I am using .net7. My normal word to html conversion happens without any error but when i have image in my doc the conversion throws an error.

Followed this example here :-

https://github.com/OpenXmlDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/blob/vNext/OpenXmlPowerToolsExamples/WmlToHtmlConverter02/WmlToHtmlConverter02.cs

```
System.ArgumentNullException
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'attribute')
Source=System.Private.CoreLib
StackTrace:
at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
at System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String paramName)
at System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute.op_Explicit(XAttribute attribute)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.CreateStyleFromSpacing(Dictionary`2 style, XElement spacing, XName elementName, Boolean suppressTrailingWhiteSpace)    at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.DefineParagraphStyle(XElement paragraph, XName elementName, Boolean suppressTrailingWhiteSpace, Decimal currentMarginLeft, Boolean isBidi)    at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertParagraph(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, WmlToHtmlConverterSettings settings, XElement paragraph, XName elementName, Boolean suppressTrailingWhiteSpace, Decimal currentMarginLeft, Boolean isBidi)    at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.ProcessParagraph(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, WmlToHtmlConverterSettings settings, XElement element, Boolean suppressTrailingWhiteSpace, Decimal currentMarginLeft)    at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertToHtmlTransform(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, WmlToHtmlConverterSettings settings, XNode node, Boolean suppressTrailingWhiteSpace, Decimal currentMarginLeft)    at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.<>c__DisplayClass61_0.<GroupAndVerticallySpaceNumberedParagraphs>b__2(XElement e)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.\<\>c__DisplayClass19_0.\<CreateSectionDivs\>b__1(IGrouping`2 g)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertToHtmlTransform(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, WmlToHtmlConverterSettings settings, XNode node, Boolean suppressTrailingWhiteSpace, Decimal currentMarginLeft)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.\<\>c__DisplayClass5_0.\<ConvertToHtmlTransform\>b__0(XElement e)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator\`2.MoveNext()
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertToHtmlTransform(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, WmlToHtmlConverterSettings settings, XNode node, Boolean suppressTrailingWhiteSpace, Decimal currentMarginLeft)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, WmlToHtmlConverterSettings htmlConverterSettings)

tried different ways to find which argument is missing but was unsuccessfull.`
``
```